# How do I retain expanded dropdown menu in a new fresh page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

It is a bit hard to explain what I am asking. So, I am explaining it using some snapshot step by step.

Initially when I load page, page looks like this:

[image]

If I click on `Python Basics` and `Python Advanced` links it will look like this:

[image]

If I choose a link like `Python Variables` [see above pic] this will show up:

[image]

as you can see, I am in `Python Variables` page and dropdown menus are collapsed, that is not what I want, I want it to look like this after clicking `Python Variables` link:

[image]

I mean even after clicking new link I want it to retain its previous expaned dropdown menu in new page. Is this possible to achieve? How do I do it?

[This link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/pass-statement) shows exactly what I want my side bar to look like when I click a new link on side bar links?

This is the code of side bar:

```
<div class="sidenav">
        {% for sub_cat in sub_cats %}
                <button class="dropdown-btn"> {{ sub_cat.sub_cat_title }} 
                        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-container">
                        {% for subsub_cat in sub_cat.subsubcategory_set.all %}
                            {% url 'tutorials:tutorials' subsub_cat.subsub_cat_parent.sub_cat_parent.cat_slug subsub_cat.subsub_cat_parent.sub_cat_slug subsub_cat.subsub_cat_slug as tutorial_link %}

                            <a href="{{ tutorial_link }}" class="dropLink {% if request.path == tutorial_link %}working{% endif %}" >{{ subsub_cat.subsub_cat_title }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                </div>
        {% endfor %}
</div>
```

and codes below are its associated Javascript code:

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
    dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;

        if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me solve it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just come up with an approach and it worked fine. 
This is what I did:

**Solution:**

active link has `working` class, if I click on any link on the side bar it will take `working` CSS class. As declared here `{% if request.path == tutorial_link %}working{% endif %}` &

```
.working{
    background-color: #ccc;
}
```

I used this CSS class as a medium to get to the parent and added `working` class to it to get to my goal as:

```
let sub_cat = document.getElementsByClassName('dropLink');

for (i = 0 ; i < sub_cat.length; i++){
  if (sub_cat[i].classList.contains('working')){
    x = sub_cat[i]

    elem = x.parentElement.previousElementSibling 
    elem.classList.toggle('working');

    elem.click()
  }
}
```

This is all what it takes.

I don't know if this is a standard approach, but it worked fine and made me happy. If you have better solutions I would really like to hear it from you. Thanks.